# Putting string variables in array, then comparing different string variable value with variable values in array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an angular page, with input fields from which I read input values and set them in variables inside .ts file. The values entered may change, so I cant hard-code values.

These are the variables I set values in using [(ngModel)]. All is good with that, values are set.

```
input1_1: string;
input1_2: string;
input2_1: string;
input2_2: string;
```

Then I want to make comparison. All the inputs ending with `_1` is put in array `fromArray`, all other, ending with `_2` in `toArray`.

Then I want to make comparison, because I don't want to have a value from `fromArray` inside `toArray`.
In a function I tried doing

```
if (this.toArray.includes(this.input1_1) == true) {
//then disable next button
}
```

But it doesn't work. I guess I need to get actual values, because it doesn't seem to be checking for actual values.

How can I manage to check if array of variables has same value as a different variables value?

This is all code together (sample from it, as its checking for other things also in the `if` statement), should make it clearer.

```
// input values from angular html input fields
input1_1: string;
input1_2: string;
input2_1: string;
input2_2: string;
input3_1: string;
input3_2: string;
input4_1: string;
input4_2: string;

// arrays for checking
fromArray = [this.input1_1, this.input2_1, this.input3_1, this.input4_1];
toArray = [this.input1_2, this.input2_2, this.input3_2, this.input4_2];

// function to run on each input field
checkValues() {
  if (this.toArray.includes(this.input1_1) == true) {
    this.disableNext = true
  } else (this.disableNext = false)
}
```

I could have just compared values to each other, but I did not want to write too much code, thought this should be a lot shorter.
I've spent last 2 hours searching for similar examples, but none helped. 
I did read about `array.some()`, but It seems that it wouldnt help me, and would cause extra code write, and `array.includes()` is a better option.

Any tip would be great.

I'm new to coding, so please be gentle and ask for clarification if needed.

**EDIT:
As requested by Jo Carrasco and Dev - I will input the whole thing:**

[StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbmo3k)

The html formatting is totally wrong in stackblitz, but it does what is needed.

The `this.toArray.includes(this.input1_1)` is only in first dropdown function (`checkDropDown1`) for now, I dont see need to add to others, as I need to check for only one now.

you can see the logic of disabling `Next` button also - all values needs to be entered if checkbox is checked, and if they are same in either of the places (either 2 dropdowns are same, or any of input fields), the button needs to be disabled.

**EDIT 2**

It seems that it doesn't update the values in array once they are dynamically changed. It takes the first value the variable had, and saves that value in array, but doesn't change it when and edit happens on the variable (input field).

-- What I did to fix it is I am splicing array value, so that whenever I call a function which should check the values in array, I am deleting and then inserting that value that I need to update into the array and then do a comparison using `if` statement inside `for`. Then I do the check inside the actual `if` statement with `equalValue` where the original `array.include();` was supposed to be.

```
this.fromArray.splice(0, 1, this.input1_1);
this.toArray.splice(0, 1, this.input1_2);

var equalValue = false;

for (let i = 0; i < this.toArray.length; i++) {
  if( this.toArray[i] === this.input1_1) {
    equalValue = true;
    console.log(this.toArray[i]);
    console.log(this.input1_1);
    break;
  }

}
```

**If you have a better solution, please write it down, I will go through it and mark as answer if it solves the issue better.**

Comment: `== true` is unnecessary. What *doesn't work* exactly? `if (this.toArray.includes(this.input1_1) == true)` should work as described

Comment: I was also thinking that I can exclude the `== true`, thanks for clarifying that.
Yes, that's what i thought that it should work.
So if I enter in the field `input1_2` value `test`, and then in field `input1_1` value `test`, it should end up as `true` thus setting `this.disableNext = true` and disabling `Next` button, but it doesnt. It stays enabled

Comment: Please post a demo on stackblitz so people will answer it easier

Comment: @dev Here's a link to [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbmo3k)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to fix it is I am splicing array value, so that whenever I call a function which should check the values in array, I am deleting and then inserting that value that I need to update into the array and then do a comparison using `if` statement inside `for`. Then I do the check inside the actual `if` statement with `equalValue` where the original `array.include();` was supposed to be.

```
checkValues() {
  this.fromArray.splice(0, 1, this.input1_1);
  this.toArray.splice(0, 1, this.input1_2);

  var equalValue = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < this.toArray.length; i++) {
    if( this.toArray[i] === this.input1_1) {
      equalValue = true;
      console.log(this.toArray[i]);
      console.log(this.input1_1);
      break;
    }

  }

  if (this.equalValue == true) {
    this.disableNext = true
  } else (this.disableNext = false)
}
```

**If you have a better solution, please write it down, I will go through it and mark as answer if it solves the issue better.**

Answer (score 0):

Please show the actual code, so we can run it by ourselves.
It looks like those string properties are undefined.

```
undefined == true //false
```

So, that's why you can't get the actual value

Try to do it like this

```
if (this.toArray.includes(this.input1_1)) {
```

Comment: Here's a link to [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbmo3k)

Answer (score 0):

if you really dont care about exact value but toArray and fromArray should not have any value same then here is your solution-
 include loadash in your project loadash - https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniq

```
checkValues() {
  if (_.uniq([...this.toArray, ...this.fromArray]).length < [...this.toArray, ...this.fromArray].length ) {
    this.disableNext = true
  } else (this.disableNext = false)
}
```

explanation -
if both array have some values same-

```
this.toArray = [a,b,c];
this.toArray = [a,b,d];
[...this.toArray, ...this.fromArray] will equal to [a,b,c,a,b,d]  // length will be 6
_.uniq([...this.toArray, ...this.fromArray])  will equal to - [a,b,c,d]; // length will be 4
// so if duplicates is present then left hand will be less than right hand in if statement
```

if both array have no values same

```
 this.toArray = [a,b,c];
    this.toArray = [d,g,f];
    [...this.toArray, ...this.fromArray] will equal to [a,b,c,d,g,f]  // length will be 6
    _.uniq([...this.toArray, ...this.fromArray])  will equal to - [a,b,c,d,g,f]; // length will be 6
    // so in this case it will go to false condition
```

hope it helps Happy coding !! :)

Comment: Not quite.
I would want to compare one value from, for example, `fromArray` with all the values from `toArray`, and after that I want to check if `fromArray` already has that value.

I dont want to compare array against array, as there could be `null` or empty strings, which would compare as existing and thus not doing what is needed.